# Tolerance in English for names with vulgar everyday meaning?

Tags: word-usage, slang, offensive-language, names

Why does English (and perhaps other languages) allow collisions between names and nouns with vulgar/offensive meanings?

I'm thinking of course of Dick vs. dick.

Possible explanations (in no particular order):

1. There is no *real* tolerance. "Dick" (the name), short for Richard, is out-of-fashion, precisely because of collision with the offensive noun. A quick look at IMDb, for example, which contains about 5 million names, yields few "Dicks" under the age of 30. So perhaps in the past the vulgar meaning wasn't quite so prevalent?
2. The term "dick" is only a second-class vulgarism, not on par with "cock" and "prick". (In fact, I have heard/read that that "rooster" supplanted "cock" because of the latter's vulgar meaning.) Perhaps "dick" as the body part is a less-offensive, more playful alternative to "cock" and "prick"? Also, the second meaning of "dick", a rude, abrasive, or inconsiderate person, is less severe than other similar terms (e.g. "prick" again, and "asshole", and "bitch" for a female). Is it possible that "dick" describes a condition (e.g. dickish behavior) while the other terms are more for permanent states, hence "dick" is less severe?

Comment: Some people might find 664894 offensive. There might even be a name for this phenomenon. However, I'd argue that the problem lay with them, not user 664894 or Dick 664894.

Comment: You left out a few. Would you please edit to include those vulgar words you've overlooked?

Comment: Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher, in tribute to her Home Secretary, The Rt Hon. Willie Whitelaw M.P. once stated at a press conference 'Every Prime Minister needs a Willie'!

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't, but the language is both too slow to change and too quick for it to prevent them happening.

Now, it is true as you say that some people favour *rooster* over *cock* precisely because *cock* had an association with penises. And if everyone both 1) thought "penis" when they heard *cock* and 2) were terribly upset about this, then the word would die out in one sense or the other and that would be that.

But lots of people either don't think only of penises when the context makes it clear that a *cock* is a male chicken, and lots don't really care besides finding it amusing. I'm not going to let somebody else's prudery get in the way of enjoying a nice piece of cock. (Interpret that as you will). This slows down the process.

Alternatively, people might get bored of a particular vulgarity; while some are long-standing, many have appeared and died out again relatively quickly. So it's perfectly possible that *cock* for penis would have died out with ironically the fact that it's now quite separate from *rooster* being a factor in it staying in use.

And lets say the vulgar use did die out. This has happened before, with for example *occupy* which no longer has a vulgar sense meaning "penetrate sexually". Let's say it happened with *cock*. If there is a remaining desire to have vulgar terms for penis (and the evidence would suggest that there was), then you'll just have more. A noun for something longer than it is wide, or something associated with male virility (as happened with the cock in the first place, which is ironic as the cock does not have significant enough a penis to penetrate a hen) or something else again.

And so the cycle continues. Language is an evolving system. It takes time for one use to become so prevalent that it encourages people to avoid the word in other senses, and then it takes time for that to spread, if it ever does.